# CodeIgniter foreach

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

I am fairly new to CodeIgniter and I'm sure there's a simple answer.  I need to determine if there are records returned prior to executing this line of code in my VIEW:

```
foreach ($announcements->result_array() as $announcement_data){
```

My disconnect is that I can't check if array is empty because it is not an array yet until the foreach line is executed. Checking if $announcements is empty also doesn't work.

**CONTROLLER:**

```
public function summary() {
  $this->load->model('Propinfo_model');
  $data['propid'] = "516";
  $data['propinfo'] = $this->Propinfo_model->get_propinfo($data['propid']); 
  // query for proposal info
  $data['announcements'] = $this->Propinfo_model->get_announcements($data['propid']);       
  $this->load->view('summary_view', $data); 
}
```

**MODEL:**

```
// Select all records from 'prop_announcements' table per prop ID
public function get_announcements($propid) {
  // Build query
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('prop_announcements P');      
  $this->db->join('ssp_users', 'P.user = ssp_users.userid');
  $this->db->where('P.propid', $propid);
  return $this->db->get();
}
```

**VIEW:**

```
foreach ($announcements->result_array() as $announcement_data){
  echo $announcement_data['user']; // example field
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use

```
if ($announcements->num_rows() == 0) {
 //code for no rows
}
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html

Comment: Thank you @exussum. That was the solution!